# Creating a prior function for Bayesian interference of a Bernoulli

Tags: probability, bayesian, bernoulli-numbers, beta-function

I am trying to solve exercise 3.12 from Kevin P.Murphy-Machine Learning_ A Probabilistic Perspective

According to the question for a Bernoulli estimation the prior is

$$
p(\theta) = 0.5 \  => \ when\ \theta=0.5
$$
$$
p(\theta) = 0.5 \  => \ when\ \theta=0.4
$$
$$
p(\theta) = 0 \  => \ everywhere\ else
$$

I need to calculate the Maximum A Posteriori Probability (MAP) under this prior.

I am unable to understand how to begin:-

a. Should I treat the prior as a Beta function and try and find x and y for the beta function using the given conditions.

b. Should I try to create a prior function that map the given conditions - if yes then what function can I use???

Answer (score 1):

You are already given the prior in the problem description. It's not defined by a Beta distribution - it's the piecewise function

\begin{equation}
p(\theta) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
                          .5 & \mbox{if $\theta = .4 \text{ or } .5$} \\
                          0 & \mbox{else} \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}

Now, we know that the posterior is proportional to the likelihood times the prior. Let $N_1$ represent the number of heads and $N_0$ represent the number of tails. Define $N = N_0 + N_1$.

\begin{align*}
  p(\theta|D) &\propto p(D|\theta) \cdot p(\theta) \\
              &\propto \theta^{N_1}(1 - \theta)^{N_0} \cdot
                \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
                          .5 & \mbox{if $\theta = .4 \text{ or } .5$} \\
                          0 & \mbox{else} \end{array} \right. \\
              &= \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
                                 \theta^{N_1}(1 - \theta)^{N - N_1} &
                                                                      \mbox{if
                                                                      $\theta
                                                                      \in
                                                                      \{.4,
                                                                      .5\}$} \\
                                 0 & \mbox{else} \end{array} \right.
  \\
              &= \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
                           .4^{N_1}(.6)^{N - N_1} & \mbox{if $\theta = .4$} \\
                           .5^N & \mbox{if $\theta = .5$} \\
                           0 & \mbox{else} \end{array} \right.
  \\
\end{align*}

Now we must choose $\theta$ to maximize the posterior.

$\hat{\theta}_{MAP} = \underset{\theta}{\mathrm{argmax}} p(\theta|D)$

It's obvious that $\hat{\theta}_{MAP} \in \left\{.4,.5\right\}$, so 
\begin{align*}
\hat{\theta}_{MAP} &= \underset{\theta}{\mathrm{argmax}} \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
                           .4^{N_1}(.6)^{N - N_1} & \mbox{if $\theta = .4$} \\
                           .5^N & \mbox{if $\theta = .5$} \end{array} \right. \\
  &= \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
                           .4 & \mbox{if $(.4)^{N_1} (.6)^{N-N_1} \ge .5^N$} \\
                           .5 & \mbox{else} \end{array} \right.
\end{align*}